# After publishing, my Azure App Service is showing "Your App Service app is up and running" on loading, how to remove?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In the past when I have published my website to the relevant Azure App Service it has just loaded.

I have just created a new Deployment Slot, and when I publish to this, it now shows "Your App Service app is up and running" as the opening page. How do I get rid of this. I feel that this is something new that MS Azure is doing, although I could have missed something.

Any advice hugely welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new App Service, a default HTML page is added.
That's the one you are seeing.
Since deployment slots are also App Services,
and it won't have any content after being created, you see the default page.

Publish your app to the deployment slot and you'll see that.

Comment: thanks for answer. Thing is I have published the app content, and I am seeing it, that is why I am surprised. I checked the "default documents" list in application settings and yes it includes "default.htm" at the top but so does all of my other app services which do work. I have check that the content is there by using "beyond compare".

Comment: Just had idea. It could be a caching thing, since I am using "WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION=Always. Will Stop/Start the app service

Comment: Oh, okay :) If you have actually published the content, then my answer does not apply.

Comment: It was a caching problem, also Shift-F5ed

Comment: @SamJolly - you shouldn't edit someone else's answer to post your solution. Either post your own answer explaining the issue or, in this case, just close the question since there was no real programming problem (it was a cache issue on your side).

Comment: @SamJolly , if there are no existing documents within the Azure App Service,(That **you** made, not **Azure**) then it will load the default.htm    -    You **can** **edit** the default.htm from the **App Service Editor** (Which is currently in preview mode)